# How can I get my texture correctly onto plane?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I am trying to add a texture to a plane but it doesn't spread correctly across the entire plane. How could I get it right?
[image]

Comment: Try unchecking Min in the mapping node, and see if that helps.

Comment: I recommend that you learn how texture coordinates work. Bartek Skorupa has an amazing video on texturing: [Manipulate texture coordinates like a boss](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAUmLcXhUj0)

Comment: Thanks it helped , the video was very interesting, but for me with my low understanding of blender 2nd day learning, i will learn it later :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, you could just open a UV Image Editor Window, choose your texture, Select your Plane's Faces in Edit Mode in the 3D window TopView ortho mode and do an Unwrap-Project from View-Bounds and then scale the projected UVMap in the UVImage editor to scale or "Fit" the UVmap to the size of the image itself.... this will also prevent repeating if your have selected the UVMAP option under your "*textures*" UV "mapping" options...

Answer (score 2):

Try UV Unwrapping your plane mesh then using the UV coordinate from the Texture Coordinate node instead of the Generated output.

[image]
*Before Mapping*
[image]
*After Mapping*

Looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUbdw.jpg

Comment: i try like in your picture but now it's black i dont know why

http://imgur.com/a/FficL

Comment: Could you post a file? I am at school right now and will look deeper shortly, but I can't make it out from this image.

Comment: Did you UV Unwrap your plane?

Comment: That's it! i forgot unvrap it thank you :) now its okey

Comment: @DimaWorld Please accept my answer if that one was most helpful for you :)

Comment: sorry but how ?

Comment: @Click the check mark below the downvote button, the green one like you did for the answer above mine.